# Show that the linear operator is zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb C$ .Let $T:V \to V$ be a diagonalizable operator on $V$ such that $T$ acts nilpotently on some $y$ i.e. $T^m(y)=0$ for some $m \in \mathbb N$ and $  0 \neq  y  \in  V$.Show that $T=0$

I think we need to diagonalize $T$ and then we have to use corresponding basis of  eigenvectors to prove this.Please help!

Comment: I'm guessing that, of course, $\;y\neq0\;$ is a given data?

Comment: @Joanpemo edited,thanks!

Comment: I think the claim, as given, is false.

Comment: @Dontknowanything I don't think the statement is true. Consider the transformation $T:\mathbb{C}^3\to\mathbb{C}^3$ given by the matrix $A_T=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. It is clear that $T(1,1,0)=(0,0,0)$, but $T$ is not identically zero because $T(0,0,1)=(0,0,1)$.

Comment: @Dontknowanything If the assumption is $T(y)=0$ for all $y$, then it is clear that $T$ is identically zero (by definition).

Comment: @wore $T$ acts nilpotently on a fixed $y$,thanks!

Comment: @Dontknowanything You wrote what "acting nilpotently" on $\;0\neq y\;$ means, and my answers and also Wore's comment give counterexamples. I'm guessing, again, that either you miscopied something or omited something, or the exercise is a "prove or disprove" question.

Comment: @Joanpemo Actually its not given as a exercise anywhere,i need the above result in proving a theorem.So i thought it will be correct but your example clearly shows that its not.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take

$$T=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\implies T^m=T\;,\;\;\forall\,m\in\Bbb N$$

and also

$$T\binom10=\binom00\implies T^m\binom10=\binom00$$

yet $\;T\neq0\;\implies$   the claim is false.